# mysql with no defaults

Tags: mysql

I found this tip on a site.

> check problematic queries using MySQL
>   server running with option
>   --no-defaults and compare result.

I will like to know how to start mysql with --no-defaults?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, from the commandline: `mysql --no-defaults`

edit: I can expand on that if you tell me which os you are running, etc...

in a nutshell, the --no-defaults options tells the mysql client not to process my.ini and my.cnf files and it uses the built in values so your millage may very depending on your environment

There are also --defaults-file=/path/to/file and --defaults-extra-file=/path/to/file options that allow you to replace or add to the default configurations, respectively

@wallyk: These are specifically options for the client I was talking about but yes, the same options exist for the daemon mysqld, i ommited the d since the question did too.

These command-line options work for both the `mysql` and `mysqld` client and daemon programs

Comment: Should be `mysqld --no-defaults`.